# Си и ncurses, refresh()

Tags: c, ncurses

Изучаю библиотеку ncurses (язык Си, система Линукс) и столкнулся с таким вопросом: что делает функция `refresh()`? В описании сказано, что без него нельзя вывести значения на экран - но это не так.. Я ввожу строку при помощи `printw` и она высвечивается на экране без всякого `refresh()`. Подскажите что же она все-таки делает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`refresh()` делает то что написано в описании, а именно:

> The refresh and wrefresh routines (or wnoutrefresh and  doupdate) 
>   must be called to get actual output to the terminal, as other routines
>   merely manipulate data structures.

Сложно сказать в чем ваша проблема, не видя кода, но эта программа ожидаемо ничего не пишет:

```
#include <curses.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  initscr();
  printw("test\n");
  //refresh();
  while(1) { }
  endwin();
  return 0;
}
```

с раскомментированным `refresh()` все работает. Тем не менее отвечая на вопрос "что же она все-таки делает" все очень просто, она копирует буфер `stdscr` в ваш "физический терминал" (подобно `fflush` для `fprintf`)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65549/discussion-on-answer-by-vonaka---ncurses-refresh).